How to move a file to trash in Dart?
The delete API deletes the file permanently. Is there a way to just move it to trash?

The question is short and clear. SO's lackwitted bot (hopefully not human) should not decide a question being "Lacking clarity" based on character length.

The concept of moving files to trash are OS dependent and for some OS, even desktop dependent (e.g. Linux have multiple concepts of trash bins and might not even have one on some machines). I can't seem to find any package (after 1 minute search) that deals with this so you might need to implement this yourself. Which specific platforms are you looking for a solution?
